# 3d button with Transparent Background

Tags: wpf, 3d

How can I make simple application about simple 3d button with transparent background?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.You can give effects to it's background by changing it's background property.

```
<Button x:Name="BtnCancel" Content="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="42" Margin="720,672,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" FontSize="22" Opacity="0.695" Foreground="Yellow" Click="BtnCancel_Click" Padding="1,-5,1,0">
        <Button.BorderBrush>
            <RadialGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.017" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FFD1CFCF" Offset="1" />
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </Button.BorderBrush>
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#9BFFFFFF" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , but can you get me the all layout of the page ?